# Looping through observable stream

Tags: rx-java

I have an stream of observables that basically emulates a state diagram. For example:

```
whenThisHappens()
    .switchMap(i -> {
        if (i.isThisThing()) {
            return whenThatHappens();
        } else {
            return nothingHappened();
        }
    }
    .subscribe(thing -> {
        if (thing.isThatThing()) {
            log("Got that thing");
        } else {
            log("Got nothing");
        }
    });
```

The issue is that I want to loop through the login until some event happens (this is in a long running service on Android). Right now I'm able to accomplish this by keeping the observable in a variable, subscribing to it and then unsubscribing and resubscribing to it in it's `onComplete`

```
obs = whenThisHappens()
    .switchMap(i -> {
        if (i.isThisThing()) {
            return whenThatHappens();
        } else {
            return nothingHappened();
        }
    }
    .doOnNext(thing -> {
        if (thing.isThatThing()) {
            log("Got that thing");
        } else {
            log("Got nothing");
        }
    })
    .doOnComplete(i -> {
        obs.unsubscribe();
        obs.subscribe();
    }
    obs.subscribe();
```

But I kind of feel like I'm doing something really wrong here. Is there a better way to accomplish this? I looked at `retry` but throwing errors just to make it retry seems just as bad as what I'm doing now.

Comment: Are isThatThing() getters? If so the setters should raise events that notify that the property has changed. In .net we have the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern/interface for that.

Comment: Not too familiar with that pattern. I'll investigate. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear to me. You speak of a state diagram, but your code showcases none. Could you perhaps include a marble diagram of what you want to achieve? Anyway, state diagrams are generally easily implemented using `scan`.

Comment: I'll try to update to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is better accomplished with a `PublishSubject` or `BehaviorSubject`.

The stream would publish items on the subject which will trigger your subscription.

Here is event stream class I wrote a while ago:

```
public class SubjectEventStream implements IEventStream {
    private final BehaviorSubject<IEvent> stream = BehaviorSubject.create();

    @Override
    public void publish(Observable<IEvent> event) {
        event.doOnNext(stream::onNext).subscribe();
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<IEvent> observe() {
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Observable<T> observe(Class<T> eventClass) {
        return stream.ofType(eventClass);
    }
}
```

See some more info here:

http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

http://akarnokd.blogspot.com/2015/06/subjects-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code it looks like you want `filter`:

```
whenThisHappens()
         # ignore uninteresting things
        .filter(i -> i.isThisThing())
         # do stuff on interesting things
        .subscribe(item -> log("Got: " + item.toString()));
```

There are two more optional arguemnts to this basic [subscribe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribe%28rx.functions.Action1%29) which are an [on-error](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribe%28rx.functions.Action1,%20rx.functions.Action1%29) function and an [on-complete](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribe%28rx.functions.Action1,%20rx.functions.Action1,%20rx.functions.Action0%29) function you can utilize if you need - but subscriptions are automagically managed here.

Comment: That part isn't the problem. The actual state diagram is not as simple. The problem is waiting for the first event after I'm done. In your code too, if there's a `switchMap` in there, once we get the item the stream ends because the whenThisHappens observable unsubscribes and the stream switches. I want it to start from `whenThisHappens() ` again once we get the `item` when there's a `switchMap` in there somewhere.

Comment: To clarify further, whenThisHappens only happens once in a subscription because of state. In the real life case, this might be something like an activity recognition event that says the user is running. Once the user is running, I don't care about the running events anymore and start looking for other events. For e.g.  I switch to a different observable that gets calorie burn from sensor data and notifies the user once they've burnt x calories. But once I'm done, I care about the next time I get a running event again, but not until then. Does that make sense?